# MutableLivedata observer triggers only value is changed

Tags: android, mutablelivedata

```
class MainViewModel :ViewModel(){
    private val _text = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val text get() = _text.distinctUntilChanged()

    fun setToA(){ 
      _text.value = "A"
    } 
    fun setToB(){ 
      _text.value = "B"
    } 
}
```

I'm observing `text` in `Fragment` like this.

```
//in Fragment
    btnA.setOnClickListener {
        mainviewmodel.setToA()
    }

    btnB.setOnClickListener {
        mainviewmodel.setToB()
    }
    
    mainviewmodel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            //TODO
    }
```

I sometimes click `btnA` 2 times in a row.
Whenever I setValue with same value (such as `A`) in a row,

`observer` doesn't trigger. `observer` triggers when only `text` is changed.
( whenever `A` -> `B` or `B` -> `A`)

I want to let `observer` triggers when I `setValue` text with same value in a row.
How can I do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using distinctUntilChanged(). Try like below.

```
val text : LiveData<String>
   get() = _text
```